# Is it possible to pass Rails variable into JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code:

```
<% @hello = "hello world" %>
<td class="text"><%= link_to project.name, project,
                  :onmouseout=>"hidetooltip()",
                  :onmouseover=>"showDescription()"%>
</td>
```

The `showDescription` JavaScript function takes a string parameter. I want to pass `@hello` as a parameter to `showDescription`. I tried everything and can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<% @hello = "hello world" %>
<%= link_to project.name, project, :onmouseout=>"hidetooltip()",
                                   :onmouseover=>"showDescription(#{ @hello.to_json })"%>
```

Comment: this works? a comma or a to_json seems to be missing. (btw, why the non-idiomatic spaces in { }?)

Comment: @tokland: it's just text, so no need to use `to_json`

Comment: To be clear, in my comment above I meant of course a quote ('), not a comma. I still don't see how `showDescription(hello world)` may be valid JS.

Comment: I have some experience with this, I've fallen myself in this same bug on uncountable occasions :-) I have no strong opinion against '#{var}', but my advice is var.to_json (even with integers), so you don't have to think for a second about the types. Let to_json make the Ruby value->JS code conversion. Also, imagine @hello has a quote inside, boom.

Comment: @tokland: you're definitely right, it's the best way to proceed

Comment: Thanks!  I will implement it that way.

Answer (score 0):

another way to do that is using gem [client variable](https://github.com/coffa/client_variable). It helps you to do it easily